# iCalendar file creates multiple entries per day

Tags: icalendar

I have script that creates a ICS file (iCalender )   which is later consumed by a mobile device .
if the event is set to repeat daily withing  two dates,  the file produces 7 entries per day.

I can reproduce the problem with the file below, simply by importing it to Google calendar (by attaching it to an email,  sending it to my gmail account and pressing add to calendar)

but I have no idea why it will creates multiple entries ,  I tried tweaking with some of the entries, only to end up with an invalid file

here is my test file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test Productions //Test Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Test Event
DESCRIPTION:Description of Test Event
DTSTART:20140825T100000Z
DTEND:20140831T110000Z
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20141231T060000Z
LOCATION:Planer Earth
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:EMAIL
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually was that the duration was several days and 1 hour (probably you only wanted 1 hour?) 
DTSTART:201408**25**T100000Z
DTEND:201408**31**T110000Z

so after a few days you would have had several of these events running concurrently until they started ending ... until the last recurrence of the last one, only one event would have been running.

Answer (score -1):

Stumbled on the aswer:

if you specify `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20141231T060000Z`

you should not  include `DTEND:20140831T110000Z`   entry

Comment: Eli,  The DTEND can and usually should be used - it helps says how long the event is. THis is different from the end of the repetitions.

Comment: please remove/correct your answer it could be misleading for others visiting this thread: `DTEND` can be included in `VEVENT` even with `RRULE` see RFC5545 section 3.6.1. for more detail.